# Changes made to app are not being retained once run session ends

Tags: flutter

Let's say I'm connected to an actual device, making multiple changes to my app and hot-reload/restart is doing its thing and life's all good.  Once I'm satisfied with changes I hit the stop button.

Now, if I pick up the phone and launch the app - it will be an older version of the app that doesn't contain the changes just implemented.

In order to get most recent changes I have to uninstall app from the phone and then go back into the IDE (VSC) and run the app once more to get the latest changes.

Is there a configuration setting that allows you to avoid having to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that while you are developing, and hot-reloading/restarting, you are working on the Dart Virtual Machine. So if you don't make a full build and install the APK on your device then once you close the development build you are working on the VM closes and the code that was running on it is lost.

To answer your question, there is no configuration that you can set to have what is running on the VM to be on the APK without a full build.